# Why version of my Darwin is 10.3, while I have Mac OS 10.6?

Tags: mac

This is what I see on my Mac:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin be-2.local 10.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.3.0: Fri Feb 26 11:58:09 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.3.12~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

I have Mac OS X 10.6.3. Why the kernel is of version 10.3? And how can I upgrade it? Thanks.

ps. I need to upgrade it because one third-party software that I'm installing (Valgrind) says to me:

```
...
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (10.3.0) 
configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 9.x (Mac OS X 10.5)
```

Comment: [Darwin version != OSX version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Release_history)

Comment: valgrind does not (yet) support Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard). See http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205241 and http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205938

Comment: If, on the other hand, you would like get the OS product version, sw_vers is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Darwin 8.x corresponded to MacOS X 10.4.x (Tiger).
- Darwin 9.x corresponded to MacOS X 10.5.x (Leopard).
- Darwin 10.x corresponds to MacOS X 10.6.x (Snow Leopard).
- Darwin 11.x corresponds to MacOS X 10.7.x (Lion).
- Darwin 12.x corresponds to MacOS X 10.8.x (Mountain Lion).
- Darwin 13.x corresponds to MacOS X 10.9.x (Mavericks).

For other code names, versions, release dates, etc, consult Wikipedia on [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) or other similar resources.

In 2010, to get `valgrind` to work, you would have had to downgrade to Leopard.

(I tried getting the patch to valgrind to work - published around August 2009 - but was not successful.  'Twas a nuisance.)

In September 2014, `valgrind` 3.10.0 compiles out of the box for Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).

Answer (score 1):

Because the [Darwin version number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29#Release_history) is different from the OS. Darwin 9 is Leopard, 10 is Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Darwin kernel versions are independent of the Mac OS/X version.  Check the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29

Answer (score 0):

The underlying infrastructure is version 10.3.0. Everything on top of it (Quartz, Cocoa, Core*, etc.) is 10.6.3. There is nothing wrong with this situation.

Comment: How can I upgrade to Darwin 10.5 or higher?

Comment: @Vincenzo, Dawrin 10.5 will probably be in Mac OS X 10.6.5. You will have to wait for a couple more point releases.